# UILabel is always nil after creating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode8

I have a view controller in which I want to add a UILabel programmatically.

```
class ViewControler: UIViewController {
    private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        print(titleLabel)
        self.view.addSubView(titleLabel)
    }
}
```

I don't know why but when I execute the print statement, the titleLabel is always nil. It is the same with tableView or button. I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: Is it nil or you can't see it? you are not adding any text to it...

Comment: titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `nil` because of the `weak` var here. Remove the `weak` and it will work.

```
private var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

Most likely, on `loadView()` and `super.loadView()` it detect that its reference count is zero and therefore remove it. So creating a `UILabel` there does not work.

Also like what @idan point out, programatically create a `UILabel` or any other UI stuff, is better to use `init` with `frame` to specify the location.